# How to use projection with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code:

```
employees = Employee.all()
employees.projection('first_name')
employees.filter('passport_id =', passport_id)
employees.order('-added')
results = employees.fetch(5)
```

Second line is not allowed:

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'projection'
```

Another approach also returns the error:

```
    employees = db.Query(Employee, projection=('first_name'))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'
```

But if I read [the doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_projection) correctly, it should be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of AppEngine SDK are you running? projection queries were added in [version 1.6.5](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/app-engine-165-released.html)

Comment: Thank you. I use 1.5.4, so this is the reason.